# Look up table using MS Excel in java or any similar solution

Tags: java, mysql, excel

I am retrieving some data from mysql database, that data is like ID and I want to look up that ID into another table (where can I create this table) which consists of all the IDs and return the corresponding value (string) related to that ID. My question is that can I create a look up table in java or can I use MS Excel as look up table?

The following is the code that I have written till now:

```
package dbconnect;
import java.sql.*;

public class Dbconnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        String b;
        String c;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","xyz123");
            Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from shop");
            while(rs.next())
            {   a = rs.getInt(1);
                b = rs.getString(2);
                c = rs.getString(3);
                System.out.println(a+"  "+b+"  "+c);
            }
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

PS: I want some insights regarding which method is possible and easier or any other method is possible create look-up table, not code.

Comment: what does Excel have to do with this again?

Comment: To do lookup operation, we can use hashmap where using id we can get the values.

Comment: I have some data is in excel(rows and columns), I have ID(retrieved from sql database) which should match with one of the IDs stored in one column in excel and give result as corresponding value(same row but adjacent column)

Comment: will that hashmap be created whenever i run the program? if yes then any way to make permanent table(not created on every run) as it will  not decrease processing speed(more the 5k rows will be there in table that i am talking about)

Comment: It will be created every time when we run the program. If you want it permanent you can have it the table itself and do the lookup. Hashmap can handle 5k rows. But it is just standalone program it is better to keep it in database and lookup.

Comment: can you make me clear about the table you are talking about?

Comment: table means physical table in database. like shop table from database you can create lookup table in database itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup table data is generated from some external system, then we can use Java Collection HashMap(Key, Value). So we can load the HashMap table before of every run, so we can do a lookup. It will be faster in lookup, but size grows loading takes time and maintenance is diffcult(i.e we need to park the data at the end of run, load the data before run).

If the lookup table is fixed, there would be much difference on every run of the program, then create a table in MySql and do select with where clause having key value passed. This approach will be easy to maintain and have high volumne of data. Performance will be good as we need not load data before the run.

Comment: I checked with my manger, we dont have permission to actually create one new table in database. So i was thinking that i can create database in client system and copy table from server side to client side database and create lookup table in client side only. then all the processing can be done in client system. Sir is this solution fesible in java?